# How to avoid publish Sources files when using maven publish

Tags: android, maven, gradle, groovy

I want to publish to local maven my library,I"m using :

```
def VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0"

publishing {
    publications {

        release(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.sdk'
            artifactId = 'sdk'
            version = VERSION_NAME

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.release
            }

        }
        debug(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.sdk'
            artifactId = 'sdk'
            version = VERSION_NAME + "-debug"

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.debug
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'MySdk'
            url = "../maven-local-repo"
        }
    }

}
```

I don't want it to generate all the -sources files which contains the non obfuscated code and from what i saw not needed for the future use of that published library.

another option is a way to auto delete these file after task is done.